# YUV values for a given macroblock in an AVFrame

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I am trying to find the pixels value for a given macroblock in a frame.
What I did is the following :

```
//for all macroblock in this frame
 mb_height and mb_width are the number of macroblock horizontally and 
 vertically in the frame
for(int mby=0; mby<mb_height;mby++)
{
     for(int mbx=0; mbx<mb_width;mbx++)
     {
           int xy =  mby*mb_stride+mbx;
        //Now for this 16x16 macroblock
        16 is the dimension of the macroblock (16x16 macroblock)
        for(int y=0; y<16;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<16;x++)
            {
                //All pixels YUV value for this macroblock
                y = data[0][linesize[0]*y+x];
                u = data[1][linesize[1]*(y/2)+x/2]
                v = data[2][linesize[2]*(y/2)+x/2]
           }
        }
         #Let's go to an other macroblock
     }
}
```

The problem is that for all macroblocks, I have the same `Y`, `u` and `v` 
value. That's is true because I only use the same width and height for every macroblock.
My question is to know how can I put difference in the above code to find pixels yuv value for each macroblock in this frame.Perhaps I must use macroblock's coordinate (MBX, MBY) or associated motion vector's coordinate(mvx, mvy) to have this difference but I don't know how to do so. The mbx and mby in the above loop are not mocroblock's coordinate but integers for the loop.
I need your help, please.

Comment: Sorry,
the first and second loops are : 
 for(int mby=0; mby<mb_height;mby++)
{
for(int mbx=0; mbx<mb_width;mbx++)
{

Comment: Please add everything that is relevant to the question itself, and try formatting your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing mbx and mby in the outer loops

Comment: Yes that is a mistake. But I added a comment under my post to precise it. Then the right is :
 for(int mby=0; mby<mb_height;mby++)
 {
         for(int mbx=0; mbx<mb_width;mbx++)
 {
...
}}